# How to disable Submit button is get method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, query-string

I want to search dog so When i click on submit button the URL looks like `http://localhost/myproject/search.php?q=dog&submit=` i want to disable the submit button is the URL navigation it will look `http://localhost/myproject/search.php?q=dog`.

My code -

```
<form id="formSearch" name="formSearch" method="get" action="search.php">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
           <td width="67%" align="right" valign="top">                      
              <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="search_text_box" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
           </td>
           <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="&nbsp;" style="cursor:pointer;" class="search_btn" />
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</form>
```

Please help me how to disable the submit button in URL Navigation?

If any jquery or javascript code please post your answer below

**Search Image Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Why is the value of the submit button a non-breaking space? How are people supposed to know what it does?

Comment: add disabled in button

Comment: @SridharR — That will stop it from being used to submit the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't give the submit button a name attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Remove name attribute in to your submit button

```
<form id="formSearch" name="formSearch" method="get" action="search/">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
           <td width="67%" align="right" valign="top">                      
              <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="search_text_box" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
           </td>
           <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top">
              <input type="submit" id="button" value="&nbsp;" style="cursor:pointer;" class="search_btn" />
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

in add to quentin:

when u use GET method the query string goes to the server via URL in the 'name=value' form.so if u dont want to show the submit in the URL than remove the 'name' attribute from the submit.
and instead u can use $_POST method if u dont want to send your query string via URL.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to customize the code with input type submit name you can use javascript or jquery

Code :

```
window.location='/search.php?q='+qvariable;
```

otherwise remove the name attribute in input type=submit

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="&nbsp;" style="cursor:pointer;" class="search_btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Here you can set method="post" in the form tag OR
- Remove name from property from submit button.

Comment: Ohk then use follow my second suggestion and remove name from submit button.

Comment: I want to form submit button. Thanks i got my solution.